# Adding json jar to classpath java

Tags: java, json, classpath

I'm very new to Java world. I want to add the Json lib to compile my program. I downloaded the file from [here](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/list).

When I tried to compile the program with

```
  javac -classpath json.jar MyClassName.java
```

I'm getting the error :

```
Note: JsonSimpleExample.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

And when I tried to run :

```
java MyClassName
```

I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONObject
    at MyClassName.main(MyClassName.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.JSONObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 1 more
```

Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: Your first 'error' is just a warning and not an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the `-classpath` when running with `java` as well.

```
java -classpath json.jar MyClassName
```

Answer (score 2):

You're making two mistakes:

1. The message you get from the compiler is a note, and not a compilation error. Follow the instructions to get details
2. You forget to set the classpath when running the app:

   ```
   java -classpath json.jar;. MyClassName
   ```

(assuming you're on windows, and you're in the directory containing `MyClassName.class`). If you're on Unix, replace the `;` by a `:`.

Note that it's bad practice to put classes in the default, root package.

Comment: `Note that it's bad practice to put classes in the default, root package.`, if so what I need to do?

Comment: Put your classes in a well-defined package. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Reason to the error was ,the  class was present during compile time and let's application to compile successfully and linked successfully but not available during run-time.

```
java -classpath json.jar MyClassName (or)

java -cp json.jar MyClassName
```

Answer (score 0):

The first output is warning from the Java compiler about use of unchecked code (like raw collections). The class file would have been successfully generated.

If you want to fix these warnings, then you can compile with `-Xlint` command line switch and fix/suppress the unchecked/unsafe warnings.